# How to disable javascript code hints in Brackets editor?

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

I am new to JavaScript, just started learning, and using "Brackets" code editor but every time I write code it's showing hints, which I don't like, I don't want to see those hints, I want to learn by myself.

Please don't suggest any other code editors, I want use "Brackets" only

can someone help please?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the code hints by going to:

- Choosing Debug > Open Preferences File opens the global preferences file "brackets.json"

Add these options to it:

```
    "showCodeHints": false, //turn off all code hints
    "codehint": {
       "JSHints": false //turn off JS Hints
    }
```

Read more on what are valid options:

ref: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#list-of-supported-preferences

Comment: There is no "Preferences" option in Bracket's "Edit" section, Although "Show Code Hints" option is there, which is "Unchecked"

Comment: Hi, I mistakenly gave the long ref and info, I have updated it. Take a look and see if it works

Comment: Thank you very much danyal, it' worked.... just added the following code to false: "codehint.JSHints":false

Comment: Glad it's fixed now. Select this as an answer if it fixes it. :)

Comment: Hi Danyal can you help me with another problem, how do I disable match tag(bracket) highlighting in Brackets text editor ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. See this if it helps: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/11502